# Cumulative sum based on mutiple condition in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cumulative-sum

I'm stuck on a problem which I think is not complicated but I can't see an easy way ...

I have a dataframe (stats_match) like this with 11 000 rows:

```
domicile              exterieur              season home   away
FC Metz               Stade Rennais FC       1999   0.0     0.0
Paris Saint-Germain   ESTAC Troyes           1999   1.0     0.0     
Olympique Lyonnais    Montpellier Hérault SC 1999   1.0     2.0
Girondins de Bordeaux SC Bastia              1999   3.0     2.0
RC Strasbourg Alsace  RC Lens                1999   1.0     0.0
AS Monaco             AS Saint-Etienne       1999   2.0     2.0
```

I would like to do a cumulative sum of the numbers of goals scored by teams/season and only on the actual teams of Ligue 1 (because I forecast to delete the rows without a team from the actual season). The actuals teams are stored in the other data frame (stade) like this :

```
equipe                  stade                   capacity
Angers SCO              Stade Raymond Kopa      17048   
Nîmes Olympique         Stade des Costières     18364   
Girondins de Bordeaux   Matmut Atlantique       42115   
Girondins de Bordeaux   Stade Chaban-Delmas     33290   
RC Strasbourg Alsace    Stade de la Meinau      26109   
LOSC                    Stade Pierre Mauroy     25000
```

I tried this :

```
d = defaultdict(list)
for index, row in stats_match.iterrows():
if ((row.domicile in list(stade.equipe)) & (row.exterieur in list(stade.equipe))):
    d[row.domicile].append([row.saison,row.but_domicile])
    d[row.exterieur].append([row.saison,row.but_exterieur])
elif (row.domicile in list(stade.equipe)):
    d[row.domicile].append([row.saison,row.but_domicile])
else:
    d[row.exterieur].append([row.saison,row.but_exterieur])
```

The code works and gives me a dictionary of my team with all the goal scored (home and away).
I don't know if it's the easiest way because now, I don't know how to do my cumulative sum with the condition on the season with:

- np.add.accumulate()
- np.cumsum()

And then how to add it correctly at the right place in my data frame? I thought to add the index into my dictionary during the loop, could it work?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this natively in `pandas`.

First, if I understand you correctly, you only want the teams in `stade`:

```
filtered_stats_match = stats_match[stats_match[['domicile', 'exterieur']].isin(stade['equipe']).any(axis=1)]
```

After this, you can simply perform a `groupby` to get the cumulative sum:

```
filtered_stats_match.groupby(['domicile', 'season'])[['home', 'away']].cumsum()
```

Comment: indeed that's what I intend to do, however when I copy your code it returns me only two lines ... instead of 11000+